# How to get tagged articles?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have three tables:

```
articles(id int)
tags(id int, name varchar(255))
articles_tags(article_id, tag_id)
```

I want to find all articles which belong to `tag1` and `tag2`, how do I write a good performance query with MySQL? Or is there a good way to design tables?

Now, I am using Sphinx for this, but Sphinx does not support aliving update index of order attributes column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* FROM articles a 
INNER JOIN articles_tags at ON a.id=at.article_id
INNER JOIN tags t ON t.id=at.tag_id
WHERE t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(a.id) >= 2;
```

And you should probably add and index on your tag names.

Also you can consider using the tag name as the primary key of the tags table, getting rid of the tag id. That way you only need to join with the article_tags table:

```
SELECT a.* FROM articles a 
INNER JOIN articles_tags at ON a.id=at.article_id
WHERE at.tag_name IN ('tag1', 'tag2)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(a.id) >= 2;
```

Comment: @barsju, your query is not support find articles belongs to tag1 and tag2 the same time!

Comment: By adding group by, you group the articles together and the having clause will make sure only those who have 2 (or more) hits, meaning both tags will match.. You probably don't need >= but can go for a simple =...

Comment: i have vote up yours ,but the query's performance not well,any other way?

Comment: Did you try indexing the tag names?